# MySQL : start Transaction if a condition was true

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, transactions, unidac

I want to execute some runtime-generated SQL commands in a Transaction, there is no problem, but I should start this transaction if a condition was true, for example :

```pascal
  SQLText := 'IF (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM desk_table WHERE Status = 1 AND Number = ' 
           + IndDeskGrid.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('Number').AsString + ' > 0) BEGIN '
           + 'SET autocommit = 0;'
           + 'START TRANSACTION;'
           + 'INSERT INTO waiting_table (UName, DNumber, MDate, HDate, HaveReq)'
           + ' VALUES (' + QuotedStr(User.UName) + ', ' 
           + IndDeskGrid.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('Number').AsString
           + ', ' + QuotedStr(MTodayString) + ', ' + QuotedStr(HTodayString) + ', 2);'
           + 'UPDATE desk_table SET Status = 2 WHERE Number = ' 
           + IndDeskGrid.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('Number').AsString + ';'
           + 'COMMIT;'
           + 'SET autocommit = 1;'
           + 'END;';
```

Generated SQL :

```sql
IF (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM desk_table WHERE Status = 1 AND Number = 202 > 0)
BEGIN
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO waiting_table (UName, DNumber, MDate, HDate, HaveReq)
VALUES ('UserName', 202, '2015/09/25', '2015/09/25', 2);
UPDATE desk_table SET Status = 2 WHERE Number = 202;
COMMIT;
SET autocommit = 1;
END;
```

but when I use IF like above code , I got syntax error

I have tried IF..THEN..ENDIF and I got same error

How can I do that without using Stored Procedures and Parameters ?!

I`m Using UniDAC and Delphi XE6 and MySQL(InnoDB)

thanks ...

Comment: You may execute first part of query `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM desk_table WHERE Status = 1 AND ....` and then you may execute second part according the result. Not in one SQL.

Comment: But I should do it in one part

Comment: What is the reason for the conditional transaction start? I can not imagine any helpful use case for this.

Comment: I should do jobs if condition was true and if I start the transaction before condition , I should roll it back !; anyway , I created a SP and using now and there is no problem , thanks ...

Comment: Well, in a **transactional** DBMS there is **always** a transaction! But you can override the default autocommit of each single statement. So this makes no sense at all. Just execute your bunch of statements with `con.StartTransaction; try qry.ExecSQL; con.Commit; except con.Rollback; raise; end;` and no transaction handling inside the statements. That will be fine

Answer (score 1):

acutaly it's `end if;` that you must put at the end

Answer (score 0):

Use local variable to store the result of the count query and then use the variable in the if condition.

```
declare @total int
SELECT @total = COUNT(ID) FROM desk_table WHERE Status = 1 AND Number = 202;
IF (@total > 0)
BEGIN
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO waiting_table (UName, DNumber, MDate, HDate, HaveReq)
VALUES ('UserName', 202, '2015/09/25', '2015/09/25', 2);
UPDATE desk_table SET Status = 2 WHERE Number = 202;
COMMIT;
SET autocommit = 1;
END;
```

Comment: I got error with this syntax , have you tested it ?!